# Fix leaking Zero G hose

Tags: leak, hose

My hose is leaking at the spigot no matter what I try.

[image: leaking hose]

I have:

- ordered [new rubber washers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08DKYD65L) and tried those (both the black ones with the little tabs and the orange one, and both).
- Wrapped the spigot threads in plumbers tape, making sure I went in the correct direction so it didn’t unwind as I put it on
- Used a wrench to tighten the hose as much as possible
- Tried all of the above together

And the house is still leaking a significant amount of water.

I do notice the washer seems a bit too small for the end of the hose:

[image: washer in the female end of the hose]

Here is what I spigot looks like without the hose on it:

[image: spigot]

Closeup of the water coming out (does not look like a faulty hose):

[image]

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Is it leaking at the top of the threads or just below?  Are the two faces/flats(where the washer goes) of the faucet and hose flat and smooth?  Think you might need a hose end replacement kit.

Comment: Does a different hose leak here? If not, it's the hose, and you need a repair kit to put a new end on it. It's unclear exactly where the leak originates from in your picture. If it's leaking from a vacuum breaker, nothing you do to a hose will fix that. If it's the hose-end leaking where it joins the hose, see second sentence. Teflon tape does nothing for garden hose sealing - that's all on the washer/gasket.

Comment: Definitely leaking out of the top of the hose threads, ie the hose does not seem damaged, it just doesn’t seem to seal to the spigot when connected

Comment: Can you show a close-up of your spigot without the hose?

Comment: Tried a different house, and it also seems to leak. Added a pic of the spigot.

Comment: Remove the vacuum breaker and try the hose with just the plain faucet.

Comment: Remove that anti-siphon valve and see if it still has the issue.

Comment: Is the hose end bottoming out against the vacuum breaker before the hose washer makes good contact? Try stacking a second washer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me the leak appears to be coming from between the lighter brass part and the aluminum-ish hose end. Considering this:

> Tried a different house, and it also seems to leak.

and assuming 'house' means 'hose', I'd suspect the brass part.

This brass part appears to be an add-on, I see what looks like white Teflon pipe tape between the brass part and the faucet body. This brass part also appear to have holes to release something outside the sealing joint of the rubber washer.

I think the brass part has gone bad. It may be unscrewable. See if you can get it off and if the hose will seal against the faucet itself.

Edit: I just saw the comments by @crip659 and @MonkeyZeus, also fingering the brass part.

Comment: Which is a hose-faucet-vacuum-breaker, which tend to fail and need to be replaced occasionally.

Comment: Often there is a set-screw that needs to be loosened to unscrew the vacuum breaker. Or drilled out if it's rusted in place.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your photos, it appears that someone has damaged the upper part (Hose Bibb Connector Backflow Preventer. It is not round anymore.

[image: backflow]

Recommend replacing it.

[image: pipe]